# XCode doesn't have executable for target

Tags: xcode, executable

I have a project that has several targets. I recently added a new target to the project but I can't build it to a device because it's missing the executable. This has never happened with my other targets; I've always been able to build without a problem. When I edit the scheme it doesn't have the `targetName.app` file as an option anywhere at all. This screenshot shows that there are no executables selected and lists all the other ones for my other targets.

The app can build with no errors, but it doesn't actually run. How can I fix this?

[image: 1]

Comment: You may have added the wrong kind of target.

Comment: @matt The target is an application target, same as all the others. I wrote a step-by-step guide when I started this project that I follow every time I create a new target.

Comment: Debugging koan: If you were right about all the things you are certain of, there would be nothing to debug.

Comment: @matt I did double-check after your first comment, it's the same as all of my other targets.